# Every group of order $5^8$ contains a normal subgroup of order $5^6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to know what theorems/ideas are behind this proof and would appreciate explanation of a more general result too, (if one exists).

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that any group of order p^n for p a prime and n positive has a nontrivial center? After that it's a nice exercise in induction.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\;p,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;p\;$ a prime, and take a finite $\;p$-group group $\;G\;,\;\;|G|=p^n\;$ . Then

Prop.: For any $\;0\le k\le n\;,\;\;G\;$ has a **normal** subgroup of order $\;p^k\;$ :

Highlights of proof: First, using the class equation, show $\;Z(G)\neq 1\;$ . Next, take $\;1\neq z\in Z(G)\;$ of order $\;p\;$  and form the quotient group $\;G_1:=G/\langle z\rangle\;$ . Observe that $\;|G_1|=p^{n-1}\;$

Now, use an inductive argument: for $\;n=0,1\;$ there's nothing to prove, and assume for groups of order up to $\;p^{n-1}\;$ . Thus, the proposition is true for $\;G_1\;$, and now use [the correspondence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theorem) (also called the lattice theorem) to end the proof.

Comment: @pjs36 Of course. Typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: why is $|G_1|=p^{n-1}$?

Comment: @grayQuant $$|G_1|=\left|G/\langle z\rangle\right|=\frac{p^n}p=p^{n-1}$$